# Ubuntu 22.04 froze and now doesnt boot. Booting via USB cannot access the computer data

Tags: boot, usb

This is what i was shown while booting via a USB. Enabling SGX in BIOS did not work. Do you have any ideas how to find out whats the problem? And how to at least access my data to move them before reinstalling? Thank you so much for your time.

[image: screen when booting via a USB]

Comment: If this is a computer (meaning no laptop) open it and try another port on the motherboard and check also the cable. It looks like a hardware issue for me.

Comment: sadly it's a laptop. thank you for your response!